# How to package a Unity Asset that depends on Addressables?

Tags: unity, assets

I'm creating a Unity Asset that I would like to publish on the Unity Store. However, this asset depends on the Addressables package and obviously require an Addressable Database which lives in a folder called AddressableAssetsData in the root directory of the Unity project.

If I don't include this in my package, the Asset won't work and if I do include it, it could conflict with the existing AddressableAssetsData of the user who install my package.

Is it possible to move AddressableAssetsData to a sub-folder of my own package or somehow configure it to not conflict with any future user AddressableAssetsData structures from another user? What would you suggest?

Comment: If I move the AddressableAssetsData to some sub-folder in Assets, Unity seems to get stuck in an infinite loop (CPU usage spike high and nothing happens for 10 min or more after that even on a very small test project)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroups folder contains Asset files that matches the groups I had created in the AddressableAssets settings.

If I delete one of these groups, I don't see any obvious errors in the Unity editor besides that the Prefabs that used to had addresses no longer have addresses which is expected.

If I restore the previously deleted group, the Prefabs that used to had missing addresses automatically get their addresses back.

So it seems like I only have to package AddressableAssetsData/AssetGroups/[my project's specific groups that I want to package] assuming that the end user will already have his/her AddressableAssets setup by the time he/she imports my package.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come back and post your findings